Deriving the formula for a torus as a surface of revolution
I am trying to do the following problem which begins by considering the circle in the $yz$-plane given by $(y-3)^2+z^2 = 1$. We want to find the formula of the torus formed by revolving this cirlce about the $z$-axis. My solution is as follows.
For every value $z\in[-1,1]$ the torus will have level curves of two concentric circles. Thus, if we fix a value $z$ then we should have $x^2 + y^2 = f(z)^2$ where f(z) gives the radius of the inner or outer circle. From the equation given, the outer circle will have formula $f_1(z) = 3+\sqrt{1+z^2}$ and the inner circle $f_2(z) = 3-\sqrt{1+z^2}$. If we substitute either $f_1$ or $f_2$ into $x^2+y^2 = f(z)^2$ and do some algebra we get the formula $$(x^2+y^2+z^2-10)^2 = 36(1-z^2)$$
This would be my solution to the problem. The solution I am provided, though, gives the answer as $$(x^2+y^2+z^2+8)^2=36(x^2+y^2)$$ which I can't tell if is equivalent to my solution. The explanation for that solution is to take the original equation for the circle $(y-3)^2 + z^2 = 1$ and replace $y$ with $\pm\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, which I don't really understand.
Am I correct? How can I understand their solution? Thanks for helping

Try consider parameterization that fit the function well, in this problem, try convert the function to the parameteric equation in form of $r\sin\theta$ and $r\cos\theta$, where $r$ is radius of circle.

Yes, your solution is correct. You can plot it using any website/app, such as https://www.desmos.com/3d

The two solutions are equivalent, as you can check by expanding all powers. The substitution $y\to\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is the standard trick to find the equation of a surface of revolution.

Parametric equation of the cirle is $y(\theta)=3+\cos\theta,z(\theta)=\sin\theta$ for $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$.
When the circle revolve around the z-axis, each point on the circle draw a circle. The radius of the rotation of the points is $3+\cos u$, so the equation is $x=\left(3+\cos \theta\right)\cos \phi,y=\left(3+\cos \theta\right)\sin \phi, z=\sin \theta$ for $\theta,\phi\in[0,2\pi]$.
Here is the visualization (Note: for the graph $\phi\in[0,\pi]$):

